# Unable to parse JSON-LD tag. Malformed JSON found: '

Tags: json, facebook-pixel

I have this error with Facebook Pixel.

```
 [Facebook Pixel] - Unable to parse JSON-LD tag. Malformed JSON found: '
```

I do not find and not understand the error. I think that it is creating another issue in Highlight.
The `unload` event does not fire reliably and listening for it can prevent browser optimizations like the Back-Forward Cache. Consider using the `pagehide` or `visibilitychange` events instead

```
 <script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "FAQPage",
  "mainEntity": [{
    "@type": "Question",
    "name": "¿Cuánto cuesta enviar un palet?",
    "acceptedAnswer": {
      "@type": "Answer",
      "text": "Las tarifas para enviar palets dependerán del origen y el destino de la mercancía, así como del peso volumétrico de la carga en cuestión pero normalmente, de media, son de aproximadamente:<ul><li><strong>1 palet</strong>&rarr;<strong>140€</strong></li><li><strong>2 palets</strong>&rarr;<strong>260€</strong></li></ul>"
    }
  }]
},{
  "@type": "Question",
  "name": "¿Cómo enviar un palet?",
  "acceptedAnswer": {
    "@type": "Answer",
    "text":"Para asegurarte de que tu envío llega en perfectas condiciones a su destino hay varias cosas que puedes hacer, entre ellas, una de las más frecuentes es contar con una agencia de transporte fiable y profesional que, además de ahorrarte multitud de llamadas y mails te consigue precios competitivos y condiciones que se adaptan a tus necesidades, como es el caso de Transeop. Consulta más recomendaciones aquí &rarr; <a href="https://www.transeop.com/blog/consejos-para-la-correcta-paletizacion-de-las-mercancias/112/">Consejos para enviar palets</a>"}
  }]
}
```

Comment: Hi anyone can find this solution. I got the same error.

Comment: This may help: https://www.sitelint.com/documentation/sitelint/seo-rules/malformed-json-ld/

Answer (score 1):

The space between name and text seems to be causing the error. If you remove the spaces, the error disappears. But it is harder to understand as text.